# Web host does not support .less file extension

Tags: css, less

I am using [lesscss.org](http://lesscss.org)'s styles on my MVC application.

It works great, but unfortunately my web host does not support `.less` file extensions, neither will they add support.

Seeing though LessCSS makes use of JavaScript, surely there must be a way to rename my CSS file from site.less to site.css and change the JavaScript to make use of the .css extension instead of the .less extension.

Please note I am not using dotLess, and compiling prior to release is also not what I am looking for.

Comment: What do you mean by your host doesn't "support" `.less` files?

Comment: they do not serve files with .less extension.

Comment: So if you upload `styles.less` and then open it in your browser, you get a `404` or a `500` or something error? That sucks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally got it working.

All i had to do is modify my **web.config** of my MVC **web application** and add the following:

```
<system.webServer>
  ...
  <staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".less" mimeType="text/css" />
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

I re-published the site to my hosting provider [afrihost](http://www.afrihost.com/), and it wall worked perfectly.

Comment: Could you share what server you are using to make this answer more helpful for others?

Answer (score 3):

The script appears to only be looking for the `stylesheet/less` rel. As far as I can tell, the file extension doesn't matter.

To clarify, renaming styles.less to styles.css and using the following code should work:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
<script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: :) for some reason it doesn't. no styles get's rendered

Answer (score 2):

Simply convert to css locally before you upload it.

```
$ lessc styles.less > styles.css
```

From the usage page:
http://lesscss.org/#-client-side-usage

You can pass `-x` for minification.